question for the simplest workflow for exporting Skydomes to GLB format
I made a fairly ‘primitive skydome’ in Blender using YouTube tutorials - with my own 360° photo of my Insta360 on the inside - but in such a way that the skydome is transparent from the outside and the 360° image is only projected onto the inside. I can also export the part as a GLB format, but it does not take the image setting with it - i.e. it takes the setting of the transparency from the outside into the export, but the image does not appear.
In Blender it looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42dCHEgw2BA
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jhc8xchnh...4hyzs&dl=0
What's the point?
As an Archicad teacher at school, I want to find a simple way to create a Skydome for architectural representations with my own real images of the construction site on my VR glasses - a Metaquest3 in the ARKIO programme, so that I can put my 3D houses from Archicad in there and give the impression that I am really on the site near the house.
https://www.arkio.is/workflow/
Such an inward-facing skydome could also work directly in Archicad... with appropriate lighting, because Archicad does not ‘snuff’ the one-sided transparency. But, if at least the shape of the Skydome as an element is inside with the image on it, I would be quite satisfied.
I can of course connect the VR glasses directly to Blender on the Win computer and then go straight into the VR scene - but my Win computer is rather too weak for this and there is ‘a jerky game’ on the glasses. I can't get a direct connection with the MacBookPro and I want to work directly on the glasses without an external connection anyway, because the ARKIO app doesn't work that badly for design work.
I've installed the ‘simple baking’ add-on in Blender, but I'm still too much of a layman to get results that work.
Can any of you guide me in the right direction?  Greetings from lake Wallersee in Austria

Here is a video that better explains what I want to achieve in upload:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbCtlT6MO38

Your Dropbox link goes to a page which says: "This link isn't quite right" and your second YT video says: "We're processing this video. Check back later.". I've never used a skydome in Blender, but are you sure that the GLB format will export image types like that? Never heard of a "simple baking" addon. I assume that's a third-party one?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-w0LFgebKs&t=334s
it bakes all surfaces into one single picture aud applies it on an uv-vertex - all in one klick and for several Forms at once for exporting.

Hmm.. That's a paid addon, so unless someone here has bought it we can't really help.

Without the addon, it seems to be possible to bake the environment picture within blender also - but much more needed steps - and when I tried it - I just get a black picture mapped on the inside of the dome. The video-Link above should now work. here again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbCtlT6MO38

All tutorials for baking I found till now just shows me, how it's made on the outside of a form - what's the normal the case. But I need it to be seen from the inside.

No idea I'm afraid. I assume you've tried flipping the Normals on the object?

Yes. I think I made the flipping - but its a year ago or so when I made this following a tutorial..

Your Texture Coordinate node is using the Object socket as input to your Image Texture node which probably isn't acceptable when exporting as a .glb. My guess is you should have your sky dome UV unwrapped and have your image mapped to the UV's. I have uploaded a UV unwrapped sky dome which is mapped to a 1024 x 512 360) image to here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/BaKQDd8R  can you see if this imports correctly into your Archicad programme along with the image texture?

That does the job for the Metaquest 3 - ARKIO-APP! Mega - thanks for Your efforts! In Archicad - I have to use some other formats and have to try further on..  And I will post the results here!

I have now added my comment as an answer. If you think this a solution to your question could you mark the answer as accepted.

Who I got working till now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0OqHL1RVL0 Thank You for Your massive help so far!

Looks good to me. :) The sky dome on the platform looked tiny yet it was indicating the correct diameter of 2 meters. It just means it needs to be scaled up to have something like 30m radius in Blender before exporting.

The "segmentierung" that you spoke about in the video is because your sky dome is using the default hard shading where as the one I sent you was using smooth shading.  See my answer below. Setting to smooth shading does not increase the complexity of the dome (actually if it works the same as in a game engine it may very well reduce the file size) both my smooth shaded and your "Segmentierung" domes look like they have very similar geometry, number of vertices and faces.

For .gltf (.glb) export your sky dome should be UV unwrapped and the UV's should be mapped to your 360° view image texture.
Then when exporting to .glb  ensure that the the UV's option is checked.
Fortunately for us the default Blender UV sphere comes already correctly UV unwrapped for our needs.
After adding a UV sphere set the surface shading to be smooth shading: Object mode > with the sphere selected > Object drop-down menu > Shade Auto Smooth.

To create the floor of the sky dome: Edit mode > enable X-ray and Wireframe mode > Select the vertices that make up the lower half of the sphere > and scale to zero along the Z axis, S Z 0.

Add a New Material and from Material > Setting > Surface > enable Backface Culling.
In the Shader Editor add a new Image Texture node and from there load up the 360° view texture. Link the output of that to the Material Output node. Add a Texture Coordinate node and connect the UV socket to the Image Texture node.
In the UV Editor open the 360° view image texture. (To see how the sphere's uv's are mapped to the image, in edit mode select all of the sky dome or simply enable the UV Sync Selection button in the UV editor).
In the 3D viewport change to Material Preview mode. The 360° view image should appear on the outside of the sky dome. To have it appear on the inside we need to Flip the face normals of the dome. In Edit mode > select All > Alt N to open the Normals menu and choose the Flip option.


When exporting, in the .glb export Options panel > Data > Mesh > enable Apply Modifiers, UV's and Normals. (Apply Modifiers because earlier when we set the surface to use smooth shading Blender created a Smooth by Angle modifier).


Adding a sky_dome bake.blend file set up ready to bake out the texture from the inside of the dome to a new 2048 x 1024 image texture using 1 Render sample and Bake Type set to Emit.

Screenshot of Baking set up using Bake Type Emit.

